# how do I override a class method so I can access it in parent class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I have a class method which I use to get class' alternative name.
The idea is to have an abstract Figure class that has a universal method for printing it's children.I want it to print that alternative name which gets overridden in every child.

Here is my code:

```
class Figure
    def to_s
        s = self.name + ' '
        @edges.each do |e|
            s += e.to_s
        end
        s
    end

    def self.name
        puts 'override me'
    end
end

class Line < Figure
    def initialize(points)
        @edges = [Edge.new(points[0], points[1])]
    end

    def self.name
        'line'
    end
end
```

...Which doesn't work:
`'to_s': undefined method 'name' for #<Line:0x00000001f12880> (NoMethodError)`

If I replace class methods with instances it works perfectly, so... why does this happen? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you make `name` an attribute stored at the Figure class, this will be a lot simpler:

```
class Figure
    def initialize
       @name = 'DefaultFigure'
    end

    def to_s
       s = @name + ' '
       @edges.each do |e|
          s += e.to_s
       end
       s
    end
end

class Line < Figure
    def initialize(points)
       @name  = 'Line'
       @edges = [Edge.new(points[0], points[1])]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops... I just figured out that you have to use `self.class.name` to access a class method INSIDE an instance. Like this:

```
def to_s
    s = self.class.name + ' '
    @edges.each do |e|
        s += e.to_s
    end
    s
end
```

it works now.